# Why is only half of my form sent?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to use post to send a form to my email address. It is kind of working, I am getting the name and message. Someone helped me with the part that is working, but when I try to add to it, what I added is not sent.

I added a phone number and bid to it. That is the first one below. I tried something else, I have seen something on here as well that did not work at all.

```
<form action="myform.php" method="POST">
    <p>Name</p> <input type="text" name="name">
    <p>Email</p> <input type="text" name="email">
    <p>Phone number</p> <input type="text" name="phone">
    <p>Your bid</p> <input type="text" name="bid">
    <p>Message</p>
    <textarea style="width:475px; height:175px;margin-left:7%"  name="message"></textarea><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Send"><input type="reset" value="Clear">
</form>

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message']; //line 5 $message now set
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$bid = $_POST['bid'];
$formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message" \n Phone  number:  $phone \n Your bid: $bid";
$recipient = "myemail";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!";
```

update this is what i have    http://jsfiddle.net/k8U3r/

I tried this too:

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name']; //required
$phone = $_POST['phone']; //required
$bid = $_POST['bid']; //required
$message = $_POST['message']; //required


$formcontent .= " Name: $name \n";
$formcontent .= "Email Address: $email \n";
$formcontent .= "Phone Number: $phone \r\n";
$formcontent .= "Bid: $bid \n";
$formcontent .= " Message: $message \n";
$recipient = "myemail.com";
?>
```

Comment: Do you have an example of the output? try `print_r($_POST)`

Comment: What out, your textarea is not closed! It should be <textarea></textarea>

Comment: @L105 I thought that at first, but it is actually hidden by a bunch of whitespaces and horizontal scroll.

Comment: @immulatin got the answer, I think.. but I thought I should mention that on your second solution you didn't declare the email variable $email = $_POST['email'], which you used on the `$formcontent .= "Email Address: $email \n";`

Comment: Editors: Please pay attention and do not delete code from answers. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have incorrect syntax. The `formcontent` line should be

```
$formcontent = "From: $name \n Message: $message \n Phone  number:  $phone \n Your bid: $bid";
```

You just need to remove the extra quote:

```
$formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message" \n Phone  number:  $phone \n Your bid: $bid";                                            
                                              ^
```

UPDATE: Another fix based on comments below:

You need to define the PHP tags, otherwise it will interpret the php as HTML and just print it out.

```
    ...
    <textarea style="width:475px; height:175px;margin-left:7%"  name="message"></textarea><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Send"><input type="reset" value="Clear">
</form>

<?php // Tag here

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message']; //line 5 $message now set
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$bid = $_POST['bid'];
$formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message \n Phone  number:  $phone \n Your bid: $bid";
$recipient = "myemail";

?> // And here
```

Comment: I removed the " and when i hit send i am seeing something like this       $name = $_POST['name']; $email = $_POST['email']; $phone = $_POST['phone']; $bid = $_POST['bid']; $message = $_POST['message']

Comment: You also need to define the php tags. I've updated my answer with that example

Comment: Yep i forgot them! now i am getting it a little more i can not see the phone number or bid, but i see Bid:  Phone number   From: ddddd
 Message: ffffffff
 Phone  number:   
 Your bid:

Comment: should i use input type="number" for them 2 instead of text?

Comment: can you update your question with the code you currently have? Your message doesn't match what is in your code. I think it is just a bit out of date now.

Comment: and type="text" is fine, probably preferred

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35389/discussion-between-immulatin-and-phil-famme)

Comment: editor does not like my format so i put it in a  fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/k8U3r/

Comment: @PhilFamme You can also use [**Pastebin.com**](http://www.pastebin.com) for PHP code and not http://jsfiddle.net/ - it's so much better, least I and many others think so. ;-)

Comment: @ Fred I was using the fiddle just to show my code because i could not get it to indent right. but i need a good place to practice with php...ty!

Answer (score 0):

in your first code, the `$phone` and `$bid` variables are not defined.

```
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$bid = $_POST['bid'];
```

And you should remove the `"` after `$message` variable in line 14.
Don't forget to check if your form data is set or you will encounter `Undefined Variable Error Message`.
like this:

```
<?php

if ( isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['phone']) && isset($_POST['bid']) $& isset($_POST['message']) ) {
    // Send data...
}

?>
```

Comment: @ WHiSPER i forgot $phone = $_POST['phone']; $bid = $_POST['bid']; but had them in there when i tried it live. I removed the " but the phone number and bid do not show. i see Phone: Bid:  this is what i have updated.   jsfiddle.net/k8U3r